# Gradle. Multi-project with Web. How to include dependent projects as class files into web-inf/classes

Tags: gradle, war

I use the Eclipse IDE to develop the following java eclispe projects:
"AuthRESTService" - The development of REST service
"AuthZcommon" - The Utilities, used cross over projects.
"AuthCore" - the core functions.

The needed external libs are placed into simple project "AuthLibs"
The AuthRESTService depends on AuthCore and AuthZcommon.
AuthCore depends on AuthZcommon.

i need to have the WAR file, that contains NOT AuthZcommon.jar and AuthCore.jar
I need to have the WAR file with class files for that projects.

Currently i have the JARs....

===AuthRESTService - settings.gradle==========
*includeFlat 'AuthZcommon', 'AuthCore'*
===AuthRESTService - gradle.buid==========

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

project.webAppDirName = 'WebContent'
def directories =  '../AuthLibs/lib'

dependencies {

    providedCompile fileTree(dir: directories) 

    compile project(':AuthZcommon')

    compile project(':AuthCore')

    war {
        description "Create a war file for the web-application release"
        classpath fileTree(dir: directories,  exclude: ['**/servlet-api*.jar','**/*test-common.jar'])

    }

}
```

==========/AuthCore  - settings.gradle==========
*includeFlat 'AuthZcommon'*
==========/AuthCore - build.gradle=======

```
apply plugin: 'java'

def directories =  '../AuthLibs/lib'

println directories

repositories {
flatDir(dir: directories , name: 'libs directory')
}


dependencies {
     compile fileTree(directories)

    compile project(':AuthZcommon')
}
```

==========

Comment: Why do you need that (it's common to put Jars into Wars), and how is the question related to Eclipse?

Comment: I need to put only own development projects as class files because some resorces are placed within, that are used by native windows dlls. And the windows dll cold't runs with resources, that placed within jar

The 3th party libs must be added as JARs.